Adding firestore to flutter app then my ios simulator not work
after i add the package cloud_firestore: ^5.5.1 then i try to run my flutter app on my ios Simulator 18.2 but then take long time and my mac get more warm and then i get long error here small part from too long error
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
2
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6D2132EB-79A5-4215-8BAC-ACC345425425, OS:18.2, name:iPhone 16 Pro Max }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
2

Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/d2/n6fwlrw52z32w600qkjhzjdw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.GxW1h3/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir57YRpV/temporary_xcresult_bundle

8
    ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'

i try also delet the package then stay same problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
